# java оператор И в условии

Tags: java, if

Как сделать так чтобы в if было несколько условий.
например

`if (x==5 и y==25) {z=10}`

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=java+%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80+%D0%98&rlz=1C1GCEU_enCA822CA824&oq=java+%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80+%D0%98&aqs=chrome..69i57j0j69i60j0l3.1274j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Answer (score 3):

```
if (x == 5 && y == 25) {
    z = 10;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Существуют четыре логических оператора - &, &&, | и ||.
>
> Если оба операнда имеют значение true, тогда операторы & и &&
>   возвращают true.
>
> Если хотя бы один операнд имеет значение true, тогда операторы | и ||
>   возвращают true.
>
> Операторы & и | всегда проверяют значение обоих операндов. && и ||
>   носят название операторов короткой схемы, так как если результат
>   булевого выражения может быть определён из левого операнда, правый
>   операнд не вычисляется.
>
> Примечание: || и && могут быть использованы только в логических
>   выражениях.

```
if (x==5 && y==25) {z=10} // только если оба верны, true.

if (x==5 || y==25) {z=10} // если хоть одно верно, true.
```